# Help with script

Tags: bash, scripts

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

a=`netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -v '1 ' | grep -v '2 ' | grep -v '3 ' | grep -v '1.1.1.1' | grep -v '1.2.2.2' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | grep -v '127.0.1.'`
ip=`netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -v '1 ' | grep -v '2 ' | grep -v '3 ' | grep -v '1.1.1.1' | grep -v '1.2.2.2' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | grep -v '127.0.1.' | awk '{print$2}' | tail -1`
d=`date`
p=`ps ax | grep $IP | grep -v grep | grep -v /usr/sbin | awk '{print $1}'`
k=`kill -9 $p`
if [ -n "$a" ]
    then echo -e "file exists\n IPs copied in .../log folder" && echo -e "\n Current date: $d \n$a" >> /var/log/offendersips.log 
else 
    echo "file empty, no abuse"
fi
if [ -n "$a" ]
    then echo "$k"
else 
    echo "file empty, no abuse"
fi
```

---

The error I get :

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
file exists
IPs copied in .../log folder
```

Comment: Your question is too inclear... You might ask questions by obeying the rules here..

Comment: What you need to, particularly if you are a beginner, is test each individual part in the terminal so each bit works, and build into the final script. as kos says variables are case-sensitive, but I think you may also have a issue with how the kill command is invoked (or why it is needed anyway), and also `ip='...'` could probably be `echo $a | | awk '{print$2}' | tail -1` as you repeating the first bit. The first bit probably also use something like `egrep -v "1.1.1.1|1.2.2.2|127.0.0.1|127.0.1."` so you don't use grep a zillion times

Comment: **To reopen voters**: [Are bash/shell scripting questions on topic? Yes.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13807/are-bash-shell-scripting-questions-on-topic)

Comment: What is your script supposed to do? The line `k=`kill -9 $p`` will actually kill the PID stored in `$p`. Is that what you want? I assume not or you wouldn't be running `echo $k` later. If you explain what you're trying to do we can give you a simpler version that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a static analysis for your shell script:**

```
   1  #!/bin/bash
   2  
   3  a=`netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -v '1 ' | grep -v '2 ' | grep -v '3 ' | grep -v '1.1.1.1' | grep -v '1.2.2.2' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | grep -v '127.0.1.'`
        ^––SC2006 Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
   4  ip=`netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | grep -v '1 ' | grep -v '2 ' | grep -v '3 ' | grep -v '1.1.1.1' | grep -v '1.2.2.2' | grep -v '127.0.0.1' | grep -v '127.0.1.' | awk '{print$2}' | tail -1`
      ^––SC2034 ip appears unused. Verify it or export it.
         ^––SC2006 Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
   5  d=`date`
        ^––SC2006 Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
   6  p=`ps ax | grep $IP | grep -v grep | grep -v /usr/sbin | awk '{print $1}'`
        ^––SC2006 Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
         ^––SC2009 Consider using pgrep instead of grepping ps output.
                      ^––SC2086 Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
   7  k=`kill -9 $p`
        ^––SC2006 Use $(..) instead of legacy `..`.
                 ^––SC2086 Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
   8  if [ -n "$a" ]
   9      then echo -e "file exists\n IPs copied in .../log folder" && echo -e "\n Current date: $d \n$a" >> /var/log/offendersips.log 
  10  else 
  11      echo "file empty, no abuse"
  12  fi
  13  if [ -n "$a" ]
  14      then echo "$k"
  15  else 
  16      echo "file empty, no abuse"
  17  fi
```

<sub>[Source](http://www.shellcheck.net/)</sub>

Comment: That's very cool, didn't know about that site!

Comment: Well, it does check many things. But doesn't appear to cover all possible uses of e.g. multi-line assignments and here docs.

Comment: thx. very useful !

Comment: @VitalikJimbei No worries, give me an upvote. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Variable names in `bash` are case-sensitive; you have no `$IP` variable set (although you have an `$ip` variable set): `grep $IP` expands to `grep`, which leads to the `grep` error and to the `kill` error.

Change this line

```
p=`ps ax | grep $IP | grep -v grep | grep -v /usr/sbin | awk '{print $1}'`
```

to this one

```
p=`ps ax | grep $ip | grep -v grep | grep -v /usr/sbin | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: now i get this error :

 line 11: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
 line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file


 ======   line 11 being the kill command

Comment: @VitalikJimbei The `$ip` variable is not guaranteed to contain a string, and you're not testing it for empty strings. Try setting `$ip` to a custom value to test this, and if everything goes smoothly edit the script so that it caters for empty strings on `$ip` (`if [ -n "$ip" ]; then [...]`)

Comment: Use $(..) instead of legacy \`..\`, Consider using pgrep instead of grepping ps output.